# how to apply constraints to the chain rule in maxima

Tags: maxima

I want to obtain the partial derivatives of an expression of the form

```
polynomial * f(x,y,z)
```

where f is not a polynomial.

I can do this using diff however it is known that certain derivatives of f are zero, the ones that have been differentiated with respect to z an odd number of times for example.

How can I apply this constraint to simplify the resulting expressions ?

Comment: Take a look at `gradef` or maybe pattern matching on `diff(f(x, y, z), z, n)` where `n` is odd.